# Enforce user agent not mobile

Tags: java, mobile, responsive-design

I have to implement a "view classic web" button in a Java application wich is responsive. I need that the application not be responsive in the classic mode, i.e. I have to pretend to be accessed from desktop.

For that, it could be enough to enforce the user agent to be desktop rather than mobile.

So, what I want is to change every request user agent to a "normal browser" user agent. Being "normal" a non-mobile and non-tablet.

I would do that with a filter that matchs every URL requests (/*), but I need to know how can I change the user agent to a desktop equivalence.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I needed was to remove the viewport meta tag. So, the browser will resize the page to make it fit on any screen, even the smallest.